# Simulate mouse movements in Selenium without moving mouse, Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to automate some task on Selenium that requires mouse movements, however I would still like to be able to use my mouse for actions on my other screen, as such is it possible to simulate mouse movements that is confined to the Selenium browser without taking control of my normal mouse?

I have searched on google for this, but nothing of substance came up so sorry for not attaching any code, but I don't even have a starting point as of now.

Comment: you can put some `sleep` between actions, giving you a time frame to perform manual actions

Comment: Problem is that I would like to continuously work while this script is running, or even run two of these scripts at the same time

Comment: If you want your script not to intercept cursor you can try to run it in another display. If you are on Linux, you can use, for instance, [Xephyr](https://nims11.wordpress.com/2012/06/24/nested-x-servers-with-xephyr/) or another X11 implementation

Comment: I am unfortunately not on a Linux, I am on a windows, any ideas there?

Comment: You can try [XMing](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) , but I didn't use it, so cannot guarantee anything

Comment: For Xephyr does that take a decent computer to run or would I be able to run it on a raspberry pi?

Comment: It doesn't require a lot of sources,but I didn't try Xephyr on RasberryPi as well :)

Answer (score 2):

Try webbot library . Its built over selenium to handle these kinds of automated tasks . Here's a small code snippet.

```
from webbot import Browser 
web = Browser()
web.go_to('google.com') 
web.click('Sign in')
web.type('mymail@gmail.com' , into='Email')
web.click('NEXT' , tag='span')
web.type('mypassword' , into='Password' , id='passwordFieldId')
web.click('NEXT' , tag='span') # you are logged in
```

> For your Specific problem you can just mouse scroll to simulate a mouse movement like this :

```
web.scrolly(100) ;
```

Comment: Would this also be able to simulate mouse movements, while I would still be able to use my normal mouse?

Comment: Yes ofcouse . That's what I am saying. In fact there is an option in the constructor in which u can make your whole automation run inside a console. (without displaying a browser window)

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! So mouse movements made by Webbot would be capture by Javascript on a website as normal mouse movements?

Comment: A mouse scroll would be . yes . If the answer helped u . please mark it as an answer

Comment: But also for regular mouse movements with clicks etc?

Comment: Yes these things are built in and pretty simple to use . See the documentation at : https://webbot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/